# MouseDragged detection for multiple nodes while holding the button JavaFX

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, mouseevent, mouse

I will go straight with the question. How could I implement a system for my application that lets me color these rectangles showed below, while holding left mouse button? And when released it stops coloring. I searched trough the internet but I still can't understand how do those MouseEvents work.

Have a nice day!

[image: Rectangles to color]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the documentation of [`javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/input/MouseEvent.html):

> ### *Dragging gestures*
>
> There are three types of dragging gestures. They are all initiated by a mouse press event and terminated as a result of a mouse released event, the source node decides which gesture will take place.
>
> The simple press-drag-release gesture is default. It's best used to allow changing size of a shape, dragging it around and so on. Whole press-drag-release gesture is delivered to one node. When mouse button is pressed, the top-most node is picked and all subsequent mouse events are delivered to the same node until the button is released. If a mouse clicked event is generated from these events, it is still delivered to the same node.
>
> During simple press-drag-release gesture, the other nodes are not involved and don't get any events. If these nodes need to be involved in the gesture, full press-drag-release gesture has to be activated. This gesture is best used for connecting nodes by "wires", dragging nodes to other nodes etc. This gesture type is more closely described at `MouseDragEvent` which contains the events delivered to the gesture targets.
>
> The third gesture type is platform-supported drag-and-drop gesture. It serves best to transfer data and works also between (not necessarily FX) applications. This gesture type is more closely described at `DragEvent`.
>
> In a short summary, simple press-drag-release gesture is activated automatically when a mouse button is pressed and delivers all `MouseEvent`s to the gesture source. When you start dragging, eventually the `DRAG_DETECTED` event arrives. In its handler you can either start full press-drag-release gesture by calling `startFullDrag` method on a node or scene - the `MouseDragEvent`s start to be delivered to gesture targets, or you can start drag and drop gesture by calling `startDragAndDrop` method on a node or scene - the system switches into the drag and drop mode and `DragEvent`s start to be delivered instead of `MouseEvent`s. If you don't call any of those methods, the simple press-drag-release gesture continues.
>
> [...]

If I understand your question correctly, you want to be able to drag the mouse over multiple nodes and have them react, all in one gesture. You'll want to use a *full 
press-drag-release* gesture to accomplish this. As documented, you have to listen for a [`DRAG_DETECTED`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/input/MouseEvent.html#DRAG_DETECTED) event and call [`Node#startFullDrag()`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Node.html#startFullDrag()) or [`Scene#startFullDrag()`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Scene.html#startFullDrag()) to activate the *full press-drag-release* gesture. Then each "square" in your UI needs to listen for [`MOUSE_DRAG_ENTERED`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/input/MouseDragEvent.html#MOUSE_DRAG_ENTERED) events. Notice that the event type is `MOUSE_DRAG_ENTERED` and *not* `MOUSE_ENTERED`.

Here's an example:

```java
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class App extends Application {

  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    GridPane root = new GridPane();
    root.setPadding(new Insets(2));
    root.setVgap(2);
    root.setHgap(2);

    // start full press-drag-release gesture
    root.setOnDragDetected(
        event -> {
          if (event.getButton() == MouseButton.PRIMARY) {
            event.consume();
            root.startFullDrag();
          }
        });

    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < 12; j++) {
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(50, 50, Color.WHITE);
        rect.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        root.add(rect, i, j);

        // detect MOUSE_DRAG_ENTERED events
        rect.setOnMouseDragEntered(
            event -> {
              event.consume();
              rect.setFill(Color.BLACK);
            });
      }
    }

    primaryStage.setTitle("MouseDragEvent Example");
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
    primaryStage.show();
  }
}
```

The above listens for `DRAG_DETECTED` events by setting the [`Node#onDragDetected`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Node.html#onDragDetectedProperty) property on the root `GridPane`. Note that if you start dragging on one of the `Rectangle`s then the event will bubble up to the root and be handled by the aforementioned handler. Also, since you explicitly mention the *left* mouse button I added a check for if the mouse button is the primary or not.

Then each `Rectangle` listens for `MOUSE_DRAG_ENTERED` events by having their [`Node#onMouseDragEntered`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Node.html#onMouseDragEnteredProperty) property set. These events will only be delivered if a *full press-drag-release* gesture is in effect.